# Parsing from DataSnapshot to Java class in Firebase using getValue()

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know how to parse a simple DataSnapshot object to any Java class using `public T getValue (Class<T> valueType)`. But after the Firebase 3.0 I am not able to parse the following data to my Java Class, as it contains a custom type instance for which I'm receiving NULL.

*NOTE: The same logic was working fine before Firebase 3.0. I suppose its because now Firebase is using GSON instead of JACKSON. Please correct me if I'm wrong*

**DATA:**

```
{ 
  "address" : "DHA karachi", 
  "addresstitle" : "DHA karachi", 
  "logoimage" : {
    "bucketname" : "test2pwow",
    "id" : "zubairgroup",
    "mediaType" : "image/png",
    "source" : 1,
    "url" : "https://pwowgroupimg.s3.amazonaws.com/zubairgroup1173.png?random=727" 
  },
  "title" : "zubairghori" 
}
```

**Group.java**

```
public class Group {

    public String address;
    public String addresstitle;
    public LogoImage logoimage;

    public Group(){}

}
```

**LogoImage.java**

```
public class LogoImage {

    public String bucketname;
    public String id;

    public LogoImage(){}

}
```

Code that read:

```
Group group = datasnapshot.getValue(Group.class);
```

It doesn't cast `LogoImage` part of the database into the `logoimage` object. We always retrieve null in the `logoimage` object.

Comment: *firebaser here* Firebase does not use GSON. We merely removed our dependency on Jackson in the latest release to reduce the impact we have on the APK size. What part is causing problems here? Can you show the minimal code that reads data with these classes?

Comment: I'm not able to parse this data into Group using this line of code:
`Group group = datasnapshot.getValue(Group.class);`

It doesn't cast LogoImage part of the database into the logoimage object. We always retrieve null in the logoimage object.

Comment: I added a non-answer below to show that your code works when I try it. I literally just import your JSON into my database and copied your classes over to a test project. I'm not sure why you are getting no results, while I am with the same code. :-/

Answer (score 12):

[image]**public  T getValue(Class valueType)**

1.The class must have a **default constructor** that takes no arguments

2.The class must **define public getters** for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

Check it from:
[this source](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class)) It'll help you

[detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDxQO.png)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why that is causing problem for you. This code works fine for me with the data you provided:

```
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("37830692");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Group group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Group.class);
            System.out.println(group);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image: Screenshot of values showing in the debugger]

Comment: This would be the perfect answer if you've posted a screenshot of the Group class.

Comment: This answer is almost a year old. But I'm pretty sure I simply used the `Group` class from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by providing not only getters for all the values, **but setter too**. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you can try add this line above your class name. Eg:
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class LogoImage {

    public String bucketname;
    public String id;

    public LogoImage(){}

}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by making sure that the arguments of the constructor are spelled the same than the elements saved at Firebase. My mistake was that I was setting the key of Firebase with Uppercase letters and object arguments with lowercase letters.